# tsyringe doesn't work properly does anyone know why

Tags: tsyringe

I'm trying to do some projects with tsyringe, but I'm having some problems. Who can help me?

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import { container, injectable } from "tsyringe";

@injectable()
class B{
    constructor(){}
}

@injectable()
class C{
    constructor(b: B){}
}

container.resolve(C); // Uncaught Error: TypeInfo not known for "C"
```

It's working fine [here](https://github.com/microsoft/tsyringe?tab=readme-ov-file#example-without-interfaces).
Why is my code not working

This works well

```
@injectable()
class B{
    constructor(){}
}

@injectable()
class C{
    constructor(@inject(B) b: B){}
}

container.resolve(C); // in working order
```